# Parse through website with Beautiful Soup to find matching Data

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying Python + BeautifulSoup to loop through a website in order to find a matching string contained in a  tag.
When the matching substring is found stop the iteration and print the span, can't find a way to make this work.

this is what I could manage to work out so far

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

num = 1

base_url = "https://v-tac.it/led-products-results-page/?q="
request = '500'
separator = '&start='
page_num = "1"

url = base_url + request + separator + page_num

html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = b(html, "html.parser")

for i in range(100) :
    for post in soup.findAll("div",{"class" : "spacer"}):
        h = post.findAll("span")[0].text
        if "request" in h:
            break
            print(h)

    num += 1
    page_num = str(num)
    url = base_url + request + separator + page_num
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = b(html, "html.parser")
    print("We are at page " + page_num)
```

But it doesn't return anything, it only cycles through the pages.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the text then with bs4 4.7.1 you should be able to use :contains

```
soup.select_one('.spacer span:contains("request")').text if soup.select_one('.spacer span:contains("request")') is not None else 'Not found'
```

I'm not sure why when you have `for i in range(100)` , you don't use `i` instead of `num` later; then you wouldn't need `+=`

Comment: Where should I implement this code? , I am keeping getting syntax,error, also I tried
    
    ` h = post.findAll("span", string = "request")`

but it doesn't find anything. The ` for i in range(100) `is to cycle through the pages,

Comment: why not use i then  rather than num? I added the else to the end of the _if_

Comment: come after for i in range(100) :  and replace everything upto _break_ and should be wrapped in print